# Yii2 authclient with Strava API

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, yii2

I have configured yii2-authclient to use both Facebook and Google successfully - both for connecting, and for logging in. I would now like to do the same for Strava but I don't really know how to do it.

I have added the Strave config to `config/web.php` and I now have a button on my login page. I click this button, enter my Strava credentials in the popup, redirected to my site where I'm presented with an Exception: `yii\authclient\InvalidResponseException`. The message returned is:

```
Request failed with code: 404, message: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html class='logged-out responsive old-login' lang='en-US' xmlns:fb='http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml' xmlns:og='http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/html5'>
......
</html>
```

The content of the HTML in the exception message is the same as that of https://www.strava.com/token, which is just their "The page you're looking for does not exist.".

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my class:

```
class Strava extends OAuth2{
    public $authUrl = 'https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize';
    public $tokenUrl = 'https://www.strava.com/oauth/token';
    public $apiBaseUrl = 'https://www.strava.com/api';
    public $scope = 'write';

    protected function initUserAttributes(){
        return $this->api('me', 'GET');
    }

    protected function defaultName(){
        return 'strava';
    }

    protected function defaultTitle(){
        return 'Strava';
    }
}
```

And here's my configuration:

```
'authClientCollection' => [
    'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
    'clients' => [
        'google' => [
            'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\GoogleOAuth',
            'clientId' => 'MY_ID',
            'clientSecret' => 'MY_SECRET',
        ],
        'facebook' => [
            'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',
            'authUrl' => 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup',
            'clientId' => 'MY_ID',
            'clientSecret' => 'MY_SECRET',
        ],
        'strava' => [
            'class' => 'my\namespace\Strava',
            'clientId' => 'MY_ID',
            'clientSecret' => 'MY_SECRET',
        ],
    ],
```